# Test of form containing ImageField resulting in type error

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to test a form that contains an ImageField and I'm getting an error.  I've tried stepping through the Django code but I keep getting lost and I can't see the problem.  I've researched how this is supposed to be done and I thought I was doing everything correctly.

Here's the error which occurs at the assertTrue statement in my test:

```
TypeError: is_valid() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here are my files:

```
# forms.py
class UploadMainPhotoForm(forms.Form):
    photo = forms.ImageField(error_messages={'required': err_msg__did_not_choose_photo})

    def is_valid(self, request):

        # Run parent validation first
        valid = super(UploadMainPhotoForm, self).is_valid()
        if not valid:
            return valid

        if request.FILES:
            photo_file = request.FILES['photo']
            file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(photo_file.name)
        else:
            self._errors['photo'] = 'You forgot to select a photo.'
            return False

        # Return an error if the photo file has no extension
        if not file_ext:
            self._errors['photo'] = err_msg__photo_file_must_be_jpeg
            return False

        return True

# upload_photo.html (template)
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="submit" name="skip_photo" value="Skip Photo" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload_photo" value="Upload Photo">
</form>

# form_tests.py
class TestUploadMainPhotoForm(TestCase):
    def initial_test(self):
        post_inputs = {'upload_photo': '[Upload Photo]'}
        test_photo = open('photo.jpg', 'rb')
        file_data = {'file': SimpleUploadedFile(test_photo.name, test_photo.read())}
        self.assertTrue(UploadMainPhotoForm(post_inputs, file_data).is_valid())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
 def is_valid(self, request):
```

You have defined `is_valid` method with a parameter `request` and while calling it,

```
self.assertTrue(UploadMainPhotoForm(post_inputs, file_data).is_valid())
```

You have not specified the parameter. Hence the error.

You can make use of the [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/#module-django.test.client) to get the `request` object in the unittest.

```
from django.utils import unittest
from django.test.client import RequestFactory

class TestUploadMainPhotoForm(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.request = RequestFactory()

    def initial_test(self):
        post_inputs = {'upload_photo': '[Upload Photo]'}
        test_photo = open('photo.jpg', 'rb')
        file_data = {'file': SimpleUploadedFile(test_photo.name, test_photo.read())}
        self.assertTrue(UploadMainPhotoForm(post_inputs, file_data).is_valid(self.request))
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I thought that you always had to have the 'request' parameter.  Feel free to ding my rep for making such a stupid blunder.

Comment: Its a honest mistake, and it does happen. :)

Comment: Dude, you rock!  Thanks a million.  After I read your answer, I realized I had a new problem which was how to get at the request object in my test.  I struggled with that for almost an hour when I happened to come back and refresh this page and saw the code you added.  I've really learned a lot from this problem.  Thanks again!